# Android webview stop playing after a few seconds

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am trying to play stream video in videoview.

Some videos stop playing after  a few seconds. I am getting following information in the **LOGCAT**:

```
04-05 21:36:28.991: W/AudioSystem(9041): AudioFlinger server died!
04-05 21:36:28.991: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(9041): media server died
04-05 21:36:28.991: E/MediaPlayer(9041): error (100, 0)
04-05 21:36:28.991: E/MediaPlayer(9041): Mediaserver died in 16 state
04-05 21:36:30.001: E/MediaPlayer(9041): Error (100,0)
04-05 21:36:30.001: D/VideoView(9041): Error: 100,0
```

below you can find the code I'm using for the play the videos:

```
    String LINK = item.getVideoUrl();

    VideoView videoView =(VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivVideoPlayer);

    MediaController mc = new MediaController(view.getContext());
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();

    return view;
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem (error 100, mediaserver died, etc.). I resolve it by using .stopPlayback(), and starting stream again. Below is my part of code:

```
private void startWatchVideo(final string video_link) {
        videoViewVA.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoViewVA.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(video_link));
        videoViewVA.requestFocus();
        videoViewVA.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer media) {
                media.start();
            }
        });

        videoViewVA.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer media, int what, int extra) {
                if (what == 100)
                {
                    videoViewVA.stopPlayback();
                    startWatchVideo(video_link);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

On practice it looks like video is just slows down